# ASP.NET Core session authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, cookies, session-cookies

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core 2.2 web application. I want to store user claims in application memory, not in cookies.

I add `AddDistributedMemoryCache`, `AddSession` and `UseSession` as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2), but when page is requested, I still see cookie data sent to server and received from the server.

My `Startup` class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            // Make the session cookie essential
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();


        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Cookie data:

> cookie: .AspNet.Consent=yes; .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.WGD7B_OvtEU=CfDJ8K-fe5FucclFpIYHgLvWwKY0RPLnAZQX6JnN1muQjDbx0UK4C310gp8L2RHdWlsHmoYJihQxtGuUB5GNG742rl7N-UgTynSNz09Jsb11kVgRcxAgQk5yaZnbcaQGQ0tiJUCoKAdwxEgykc2Fc3-vVCY; .AspNetCore.Identity.Application=CfDJ8K-fe5FucclFpIYHgLvWwKaod7oR4502P-cppU0aQI_WYHsvaTEL-Y5Ca1hnJOBznUpadpPkq5ubrH04UhMBpXTnK1ASjuMXMPBhr3PKqPSnXPYPFmhgki1_RicCVDQyl7mRYuWPUY2RjVkgoEIXCBj96zCRK9PWZo0N6N4hAETl-z0LAExj1Sjo6Xz3uWvHsg5GtJijlQmE6BjSh0ObMulxgDFJZEw13IbWJmlLFv7kdvs9va59wBPlEhHFER1Rs0iKW2cpVqQTPK7SjgQrSlo8_KQYHWzYa3xFSjuhrWJnm-Y4u9jXA6yCoaVxG1U-1EbOaQRfUXFs2F9IX6dU7iExsNqhPR4o2CKlt6ERI0JT_p7jHv0hrHbBiUjUVMYi_qoAQRv1OXfVZBLkoRve20gvjQtD3aRZFZR5poX-bq0pw6CNBTLexzD_bU1jJnpaf61OKbQM2-qJnWPS7YayFjJt3k_qALbnquUsSBMDMm3PoFcU26_Ubyu6RTZ-aanKc1bdcEA5o3WF8JksZkrvRFhZZuvWahDpnQCxxy-rELKwXcybcWHi-QB7gxSm6Q6S84NX2390mbHVJ1RO8eUmUF4

How can I make it store only in memory, not in cookies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set [SessionStore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.sessionstore?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for identity cookie authentication, so your authentication cookie is only an identifier.

Instead of

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
```

Use this

```
services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    o.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
}).AddIdentityCookies(o =>
{
    o.ApplicationCookie.PostConfigure(cookie => cookie.SessionStore = new MemoryCacheTicketStore());
});

services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>(o =>
{
    o.Stores.MaxLengthForKeys = 128;
}).AddDefaultUI()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

**MemoryCacheTicketStore.cs**

```
public class MemoryCacheTicketStore : ITicketStore
{
    private const string KeyPrefix = "AuthSessionStore-";
    private IMemoryCache _cache;

    public MemoryCacheTicketStore()
    {
        _cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
    }

    public async Task<string> StoreAsync(AuthenticationTicket ticket)
    {
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        var key = KeyPrefix + guid.ToString();
        await RenewAsync(key, ticket);
        return key;
    }

    public Task RenewAsync(string key, AuthenticationTicket ticket)
    {
        var options = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions();
        var expiresUtc = ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc;
        if (expiresUtc.HasValue)
        {
            options.SetAbsoluteExpiration(expiresUtc.Value);
        }
        options.SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromHours(1)); // TODO: configurable.

        _cache.Set(key, ticket, options);

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task<AuthenticationTicket> RetrieveAsync(string key)
    {
        AuthenticationTicket ticket;
        _cache.TryGetValue(key, out ticket);
        return Task.FromResult(ticket);
    }

    public Task RemoveAsync(string key)
    {
        _cache.Remove(key);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: i get en error 'InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'.'

Comment: Did you also remove AddEntityFrameworkStore ? If so bring them back